# Different ways to use properties file in j2ee app

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, properties, struts2, glassfish

I have a j2ee app using Struts2.  I have a gloabl properties file which is declared in `struts.properties` which resides in `WEB-INF/classes`.  It has the following setting:

```
struts.custom.i18n.resources=mypropertyfile
```

`mypropertyfile` also resides in `WEB-INF/classes`

Say for example it contains the following:

```
pdf.test.title=PDF Test
```

then on jsp I use the following to make use of the property file

```
<s:text name="pdf.test.title"/>
```

This setup was working on Sun App server 8.2 but is not working on GlassFish App Server (I see `pdf.test.title` on the browser rather than `PDF Test`).  I do not have access to GlassFish App server to try and tweak the setting to make it work.  So I want to make changes to the code and see if that will help.

**My question is:**

What are some other ways to use properties file in a J2EE app? (using Struts2 or not).  I'm also open to ways suggested to make changes on glassfish to make this work?

Build/version #'s

GlassFish = 9.1_02 (build b04-fcs)

Struts2 = 2.0.6

JRE6

Comment: What confuses me is that you're asking for *other ways* instead of help to *solve the problem* ? Why are you looking for workarounds instead of solutions?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm in an environment where we do not control or have access to the Application server we deploy our code to. I can ask someone who maintains that server to make a fix but it is a lenghty process.  If I can make few changes on my code side and those work then I can avoid tangling with 10 people.  Also fix on Glassfish side will involve trial and error. It will be loop where I go through 5 people to make every change. i know...FML

Comment: You may want to edit your question to include relevant info like:
OS info, GlassFish version info, Struts version info (specific release info).

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your code to use "property" instead of "name":

```
<s:text property="pdf.test.title"/>
```

Comment: This will not work. name is a required attribute to s:text tag